# How do I create a new column of max values of a column(corresponding to specific name) using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, max, pandas-loc

I'm wondering if it is possible to use Pandas to create a new column for the max values of a column (corresponding to different names, so that each name will have a max value).

For an example:

```
name    value    max
Alice    1        9
Linda    1        1
Ben      3        5
Alice    4        9
Alice    9        9
Ben      5        5
Linda    1        1
```

So for Alice, we are picking the max of 1, 4, and 9, which is 9. For Linda max(1,1) = 1, and for Ben max(3,5) = 5.

I was thinking of using `.loc` to select the `name == "Alice"`, then get the max value of these rows, then create the new column. But since I'm dealing with a large dataset, this does not seem like a good option. Is there a smarter way to do this so that I don't need to know what specific names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupby and taking a max gives the max by name, which is then merged with the original df

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['name'])['value'].max().reset_index(), 
         on='name').rename(
                    columns={'value_x' : 'value', 
                             'value_y' : 'max'})
```

```
    name    value   max
0   Alice   1   9
1   Alice   4   9
2   Alice   9   9
3   Linda   1   1
4   Linda   1   1
5   Ben     3   5
6   Ben     5   5
```

Comment: Why do you use merge?

Comment: merging with a df, that has the max for each of the names. The required output needs a max for a name against each of its occurrence. So, 9 should be against each of three rows for Alice that has values of 1, 4, and 9.

Comment: Thank you, is 'value_x' and 'value_y' built in? Also, I tried df['max'] = df.groupby(['name'])['value'].max(), and max column all have nan values, not sure why. Do I have to use merge?

Comment: Oh I see why, I printed it out, so the groupby method does not give the same length, therefore, merge is necessary. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Another very similar:  `df.merge(df.groupby('name').max(), on='name', suffixes=('', 'x')).rename(columns={'valuex': 'max'})`

Comment: Hi @Nan , I renamed the columns in subsequent edit. when two DF are merged and have the common name, there is an option to add suffix to it, as default _x, _y are added respectively for the left and right df in merge.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `transform` or `map`

```
df['max'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].transform('max')
```

or

```
df['max'] = df['name'].map(df.groupby('name')['value'].max())
```